# Autocompletion is not working in Xcode 7.2.1

Tags: xcode, swift

I have an init in *Tile.swift*:

```
init(cellFrame:CGRect, padding:CGFloat, text: String, index: TileIndex,  boundRect: CGRect) {
    ....
}
```

but I'm seeing an old version (from a previous save) of the init() from my unit test file when trying to autocomplete it.

[image]

I've cleaned the project, but that does not bring the autocorrect symbols up to date.

I cleaned up derived data and things got worse.  Same worse result after restarting XCode.

[image]

Other Symptoms.
The autocomplete on this file was working at one time and something changed during a refactoring of the Tile class (I don't know what).

The Tile type is visible (autocomplete working) from files in the main product target files, but not in the test target file.

What is the proper magic sequence I'm missing?

Comment: The compiler doesn't know the type of - I think it's- title. You forgot to declare the type in interface builder or some var has another type than you think it has.

Comment: @user965972 The Tile class is not even used by interface builder.  It's more of a model class (I am removing the view component to make it more like a ViewModel class).

Comment: I don't know exactly what the problem is with your code, only that when I see an <<error type>> it means I forgot to define a type somewhere or that I am dealing with another type than expected. So check that tile has the type that you expect it to have.

Comment: Interesting!  This is definitely a clue.  One other clue I'm noticing,  the code files in the main target can see the "Tile" class, and do autocomplete OK. but not in the unit test target.  I think the the build configuration may be incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.  While doing the refactor there were many expected compile errors.  The Tile class file compiled OK but another class in the that module was failing the compile. I just wanted my unit test to work so I was ignoring the other files errors and cleaning up the errors in my unit test file.

While working on the content, I didn't notice an error way up at the top test of the test file.

@testable import myAppModule    ERROR: No such module ‘myAppModule’.

Apparently, ANY ERRORS IN ANY OF THE FILES hides the whole module from the unit test file.

Solution: Remove all compile errors from the module under test in order for a unitTest file to see the module.

I understand it, but I don't like it.

I wonder I Apple could improve on this behavior?  Comments welcome.

Comment: Yes. Please file a bug with Apple, as compile errors should not completely break autocomplete. One of the most annoying things ever, especially, as you saw, during a refactor, when all sorts of things could be broken.